# non zeros per columns per subgroup data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
ID<-c(rep("A", times=6), rep("B", times=5), rep("c", times=4))
V1<-c(1,2,3,0, 0,6, 1, 2, 3, 0,0, 1, 0,0,0)
V2<-c(1,2,0,0, 0,6, 1, 2, 0, 0,0, 1, 3,0,0)
V3<-c(1,2,0,0, 0,6, 1, 2, 3, 0,0, 1, 3,5,0)
df<-data.frame(ID,V1, V2, V3)
```

I would like to return column number, ID or data frame where the non zero numbers `!=0` are at least 3 in each subgroup `A, B, C` 
In the example

```
   ID V3
1   A  1
2   A  2
3   A  0
4   A  0
5   A  0
6   A  6
7   B  1
8   B  2
9   B  3
10  B  0
11  B  0
12  c  1
13  c  3
14  c  5
15  c  0
```

I know how to count `!=0` with

```
apply(df, 2, function(c)sum(c!=0))
```

V1 is out because of the subgroup C, V2 is out because of the subgroups B and C

Comment: Why? V3 has at least 3 non zero for each subgroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea via base R,

```
df[Reduce(`+`, lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(i) colSums(i != 0) >= 3)) == (length(unique(df$ID)))]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    ID V3
> 1   A  1
> 2   A  2
> 3   A  0
> 4   A  0
> 5   A  0
> 6   A  6
> 7   B  1
> 8   B  2
> 9   B  3
> 10  B  0
> 11  B  0
> 12  c  1
> 13  c  3
> 14  c  5
> 15  c  0
> ```

Comment: I have a problem, it  returns me an empty data frame with this df `ID<-c(rep("A", times=100), rep("B", times=40), rep("c", times=20))
V1<-1:160
V2<-rep(0, 160)
df<-data.frame(ID,V1, V2)`

Comment: @Al14 Oh, I have an error at the end of it. Corrected. Try it now

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise_all(funs(sum(.!=0)==3))  %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(V1:V3), funs(all)) %>%
   unlist %>%
   c(TRUE, .) %>%
   extract(df, .)
#   ID V3
#1   A  1
#2   A  2
#3   A  0
#4   A  0
#5   A  0
#6   A  6
#7   B  1
#8   B  2
#9   B  3
#10  B  0
#11  B  0
#12  c  1
#13  c  3
#14  c  5
#15  c  0
```

---

Or we can use `base R`

```
df[c(TRUE, !colSums(!rowsum(+(df[-1]!=0), group= df$ID) == 3))]
```

Comment: But this take in consideration only V3 and does not check V1 and V2?

Comment: @AL14 It does check it.  If you look at the `apply` solution

Comment: @Al14  If you are talking about the 'V3' coumn in output it is the same coumn name you showed in the output

Comment: But I wan to check every column before V3

Comment: @Al14 It is already done in the `apply`.  Please check the code before you say that i didn't run it

Comment: I am testing it and changed V1 with non zero values an returns only ID and V3 with V1 values. It should return ID V1 V3

Comment: @Al14  I think I missed your logic.  COrrected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166311/discussion-between-al14-and-akrun).